# Java: Calling super after moving code to another class

Tags: java, super

I have a method that gets overridden and in this method super is used to call the method that is overridden. The code within this method however is something I use in several classes and I want to therefore reuse this code by putting it into a single method in just one class. But since this code uses the keyword super, I am not sure how to pass a reference of the overridden method to my new method. For example, here is the original method inc class1:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   /* Lots of code goes here, followed by the super call */
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In class2:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   /* Code from class1 gets relocated here. But how do I call super on the original method? */

}
```

Comment: [Delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless class 2 is a common ancestor of your class 1, you can't invoke it with super. If you moved your code to another class not related by inheritance you would be forced to use object composition, that is, your class 1 (where super invocation resides today) will need an object reference to a class 2 (where code has been move to) object in order to gain access to the given method.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   /* Lots of code goes here, followed by the super call */
   return this.myRef.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the method in question static, in whose case you could gain access to it through the class exposing it (let's say it's called Util).

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
       /* Lots of code goes here, followed by the super call */
       return Util.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Depending on what the method does, though, making it static may not be an option.

Comment: "your class 1 will need an object reference to a class 2 object in order to gain access to the method" - But I want it the other way around. Class2 needs to access the method in class1.

Comment: @AndroidDev In you example your class1 is the one invoking super in a common ancestor. You're moving the code of this common ancestor to a class2, right?

Comment: Yes. And super actually appears many times in that code but I kept it simple and only showed it once. I'm not moving the code from the common ancestor. I am moving the code from class1 to class2. The onOptionsItemSelected still remains in class1. class1 inherits from some other class.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make Class2 extend the same class as Class1.

The rest of this answer assumes that Class1 does not inherit from Class2.

Without further context, it's hard to say whether this is appropriate, but you could try changing

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

to

`public static boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, and call

`YourClassName.onOptionsItemSelected(yourArgument)`

Comment: I don't see how super gets called in any of that.

Comment: `super` may not be able to be used the way you want it to. It's hard to tell without the class hierarchy of your example. It is not specified whether `Class1` and `Class2` extend the same class, or if `Class2` extends `Class1` or vice-versa.